How to create a stateless input with Yew
How can I create a stateless input component which has no business logic and it should be a complete stateless component where everything comes through props. No validation functions or any "intelligence".Validation should be done by the parent node for example.
I would also want to make sure the properties are type safe, for example depending on which input_type we're using, there may be other additional properties (e.g. max/min value). Make sure these additional properties are only possible for the correct input_type (e.g. max/min value probably makes sense for input_type=number, but not for input_type=file)
So the end result example I would want to create my input with type text and placeholder only by sending props, something like this:
<input type={InputType::Text} placeholder={"search:"}/> 
I don't have that much experience with Yew or React, thus I am asking here, because I need this for a project to solve

...that doesn't really make much sense. Input components by definition have state: the input the user is trying to input. If you validate that state in a parent component and immediately re-render overriding any local component state with props if it's e.g. a validated text input the user will be literally unable to type in the box. Validation is something you do on blur or whatever the yew equivalent is where you propagate the local input state (if valid) back up the component hierarchy.

If you want a "stateless" component, just don't try to mutate any state. Surely you agree that fn test() -> Html { html! { <div/> } } is stateless. You should include what you have tried and describe where it went wrong.
